# Spring @Secured and @PreAuthorize doesn`t work properly(always status 403)

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have JWT authorization in my Spring REST application. Everything works good until I annotate some methods in controller with @Secured or @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SOME')"). In this case I get status 403 everytime I send requests to these methods. What is wrong with my code?

**WebSecurity**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService,
                       BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder
    ) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/person/activate/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }


}
```

**MyUserPrincipal**

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private Person user;
    MyUserPrincipal(Person user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getName()));

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isEnabled();
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private PersonRepo personRepo;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(PersonRepo personRepo) {
        this.personRepo = personRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Person person = personRepo.findByEmail(email);
        if (person != null) {
            logger.debug("role " + person.getRole().getName());
            return new MyUserPrincipal(person);
        }
        else {
            logger.error("user not found or inactive : " + person.getEmail());
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
        }
    }

}
```

**MethodSecurityConfiguration**

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class);

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }



    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {

            Person creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), Person.class);
            logger.debug("login attempt " + creds.getEmail());
                return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                creds.getEmail(),
                                creds.getPassword(),
                                new ArrayList<>())
                );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("unsuccessful attempt " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) {

        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        logger.debug("successful log in, token : " + token);
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthorizationFilter**

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {

            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MyUserPrincipal class I have found the below line.

```
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getName()));
```

Could you please check how the role is saved in the database. Since you have @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SOME')") sometime if your role is not saved as ROLE_SOME in the database probably you will get 403 error.

If your role in database is saved as 'SOME' in database then try to change the code as below.

```
  authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getRole().getName()));
```